# Alignment Kinect OpenNI 2.2

Tags: kinect, openni, camera-calibration

I know device.setImageRegistrationMode(openni::IMAGE_REGISTRATION_DEPTH_TO_COLOR ) doesn't support Kinect, so is there any other way to quickly and efficiently align rgb and depth on the kinect using OpenNI 2.2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the method you have posted up, does not work with "kinect for windows" but only supported by "kinect for xbox360"
But you can try to do this after creating your Devices and your VideoModes

`device.setImageRegistrationMode(IMAGE_REGISTRATION_DEPTH_TO_COLOR);
device.setDepthColorSyncEnabled( true );`